Call back with tables from multiple tab layout interacting with each other
I am trying to build an dash app that has two tabs and each of them have the table. I want to be able to add the rows from one tab to another tab table. For example, if I click add from recommended candidates table it should add that candidate to the candidate tab table and vice versa.
I have tried the following but I am having issue with the call back as it is not triggering it when I select a row and click "Add" from the action column.

import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

# Sample data for demonstration
candidates_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Candidate 1', 'Candidate 2', 'Candidate 3'],
    'Age': [30, 25, 28]
})

recommended_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Recommended 1', 'Recommended 2'],
    'Age': [32, 27],
    'Action': ['Add', 'Add']
})

# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

# Define app layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs(id='tabs-example', value='tab-1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Candidates', value='tab-1'),
        dcc.Tab(label='Recommended Candidates', value='tab-2'),
    ]),
    html.Div(id='tabs-content')
])

# Callback to render the content of the tabs
@app.callback(
    Output('tabs-content', 'children'),
    Input('tabs-example', 'value')
)
def render_content(tab):
    if tab == 'tab-1':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Candidates'),
            generate_table(candidates_df, 'candidates-table'),
        ])
    elif tab == 'tab-2':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Recommended Candidates'),
            generate_table(recommended_df, 'recommended-table'),
        ])
    else:
        return html.Div("404 Error: Page not found")

# Callback to handle adding a candidate
@app.callback(
    Output('candidates-table', 'data'),
    Input('recommended-table', 'active_cell'),
    State('recommended-table', 'data'),
    State('candidates-table', 'data'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def add_candidate(active_cell, recommended_data, candidates_data):
    if active_cell and active_cell['column_id'] == 'Action':
        row_index = active_cell['row']
        candidate_to_add = {k: recommended_data[row_index][k] for k in ['Name', 'Age']}
        candidates_data.append(candidate_to_add)
        print(f"Added candidate: {candidate_to_add}")  # Debugging statement
        return candidates_data
    print("Callback triggered but no action taken")
    return candidates_data

# Function to generate a Dash DataTable
def generate_table(dataframe, table_id, editable=True):
    columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in dataframe.columns]
    return dash_table.DataTable(
        id=table_id,
        columns=columns,
        data=dataframe.to_dict('records'),
        editable=editable
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)



Both tables must be initially created in the layout so that the callback can be properly registered and triggered, and also because if you "click add from recommended candidates table it should add that candidate to the candidate tab table and vice versa".
You could also define the tables directly as children of their respective dcc.Tab, and get rid of the render_content callback (just a suggestion).
# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

# Function to generate a Dash DataTable
def generate_table(dataframe, table_id, editable=True):
    columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in dataframe.columns]
    return dash_table.DataTable(
        id=table_id,
        columns=columns,
        data=dataframe.to_dict('records'),
        editable=editable
    )

# Define app layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs(id='tabs-example', value='tab-1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Candidates', value='tab-1', children=[
            html.Div([
                html.H3('Candidates'),
                generate_table(candidates_df, 'candidates-table')
            ])
        ]),
        dcc.Tab(label='Recommended Candidates', value='tab-2', children=[
            html.Div([
                html.H3('Recommended Candidates'),
                generate_table(recommended_df, 'recommended-table'),
            ])
        ])
    ])
])

# Callback to handle adding a candidate
@app.callback(
    Output('candidates-table', 'data'),
    Input('recommended-table', 'active_cell'),
    State('recommended-table', 'data'),
    State('candidates-table', 'data'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def add_candidate(active_cell, recommended_data, candidates_data):
    print('add_candidate', active_cell)
    if active_cell and active_cell['column_id'] == 'Action':
        row_index = active_cell['row']
        candidate_to_add = {k: recommended_data[row_index][k] for k in ['Name', 'Age']}
        candidates_data.append(candidate_to_add)
        print(f"Added candidate: {candidate_to_add}")  # Debugging statement
        return candidates_data
    print("Callback triggered but no action taken")
    return candidates_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


